# How do I force a Windows 8.1 Tablet to boot from a USB stick?

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, 32-bit

I've got *Dell Venue 8* with  Windows 8.1 (32 bit)  Dell tablet (no keyboard).

How do I get it to boot from the USB Repair drive (USB Stick) when it starts up?

USB is formatted FAT32.

Comment: Exact model name would probably be helpful.

Comment: Doesn't say on it so I can't get the exact model. But it's a Dell Venue 8

Comment: I did figure out how to get to the basic BIOS but USB isn't listed in the Boot order and I can't see a way to add it.  : You can access the "basic" bios by holding **volume down** **while pressing the power button when the tablet is off** (not sleep, but actually shut down).. Hold the volume down until the bios screen appears..

Answer (score 3):

1. **Access the BIOS** on boot up

   You can access the "basic" bios by holding volume down while pressing the power button when the tablet is off (not sleep, but actually shut down).. Hold the volume down until the bios screen appears
2. Go to the Boot menu in BIOS
3. Go to the boot devices.  My USB drive was listed but listed *last*.
4. You'll need to select each item and change it. I started with the last item (my USB drive) and then just set each one to the item above it until I got to the #1 slot (the USB drive)

Comment: How to do it on a tablet without physical keyboard? Volume buttons can move selection (in only first column) but don't allow to "confirm" it in bios menu.  My USB keyboard connected with OTG is not recognized in bios. Bluetooth keyboard of course doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

To access the UEFI firmware, you must enter the "Advanced Startup" settings in Windows 8.1.
If you swipe from the right, and click on Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Update and Recovery -> Recovery -> Advanced Startup (Restart Now).